# The Recurrence T(n)= 2T(n-1) + (2^n)

Tags: algorithm, iteration, recurrence

Can someone please help me with this ?

> **Use iteration method to solve it.** T(n)= 2T(n-1) + (2^n) , T(0) = 1

Explanation of steps would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to solve the recursion as follows

T(n)= 2T(n-1) + 2^n

T(n-1) = 2T(n-2) + 2^(n-1)

T(n-2) = 2T(n-3) + 2^(n-2)

T(n-3) = 2T(n-4) + 2^(n-3)

...

T(0) = 1

Then:

T(n) = 2^k * T(n-k) + ... Here's where I get stuck.

Comment: What have you tried? Where in your code are you getting stuck? Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: What is the value of T(n) when n is 1

Comment: Recursion is tempting here, but an iterative approach could be to iterate from `1` to `n` (knowing that `T(0)` is `1`) and reuse the previous iteration's result in the current iteration's calculation. Stack Overflow is about helping you fixing bugs in code you wrote though, so I'm afraid you'll need to share some attempts first ;)

Comment: Alright I edited and added some more information...

Comment: `T(n) = (n + 1) * 2^n` where `^` means *raising into power*. **C#** Code `int T(int n) => (n + 1) * (1 << n);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's compute some values for small `n`:

```
T(0) =   1
T(1) =   4
T(2) =  12
T(3) =  32
T(4) =  80
T(5) = 192
```

the function seems to be exponetial; we have `2^n` term that's why let's check if

```
T(n) = f(n) * 2^n
```

where `f(n)` is some unknown function. If we divide by `2^n` we have `f(n) = T(n) / 2^n`

```
T(0) / 2^0 = 1
T(1) / 2^1 = 2
T(2) / 2^2 = 3
T(3) / 2^3 = 4
```

Looks quite clear that `f(n) = n + 1` and

```
T(n) = (n + 1) * 2^n
```

Now let's *prove* it by **induction**.

**Base:** it holds for `n = 0`: `(0 + 1) * 2^0 = 1`

**Step:** from `T(n - 1) = n * 2^(n - 1)` we have

```
 T(n) = 2 * T(n - 1) + 2^n =
      = 2 * n * 2^(n - 1) + 2^n =
      = n * 2^n + 2^n =
      = (n + 1) * 2^n
```

So, if `T(n - 1)` holds, `T(n)` holds as well.

**Q.E.D.**

Closed formula for

```
T(n) = 2T(n-1) + (2^n) 
T(0) = 1
```

Is

```
T(n) = (n + 1) * 2^n
```

**Cheating way:** try [oeis](https://oeis.org/) (on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences) and you'll find [A001787](https://oeis.org/A001787)

Comment: Undoubtedly the smartest answer, but I _feel_ like the exercise was more about having the student write an algorithm that follows an iterative approach (e.g. `for (i=1; i<=n) x = 2*x + 2^i` with `x` initialised to `1`, or something along those lines), rather than directly resolving the issue into a closed formula. I would guess your answer is where the teacher wants to land eventually. But yeah, just my two cents, nice write-up!

Comment: Is there any easy method that helps to find the closed formulas? Something you can recommend me in my studies? I'm having a lot of difficulty.

Comment: @Jhonathan Alves: there are some tecnics: telescoping, characteristcs roots: http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_recurrence.html, https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf however, there are no *universal* algorithm of finding closed formula